# Bf3 on pc won't start up

Tags: battlefield-3

I bought bf3 recently on disc and installed it to my computer. It took about 4 hours (strange?) but when I tried to start the game it took abou 10 seconds untill this message popped out:

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing
>   this action  please install a program or, if one is already installed
>   creat an association in the defaultprograms control panel

I tried repairing the installation and it updated at the same time but when I tried again the same problem occured.

Has anyone had the same problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Go to your Control Panel, click Programs, go to Default Programs and click "Set your Default Programs." In the left side of the screen, choose your internet browser (the one you normally use to open battlelog) and below the info box, click "Set this program as Default." ([Source](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/7569987.page))

If this does not work, you can try disabling your firewall (you may have to uninstall before disabling, though).